# Windows and Ubuntu cant be load. Laptop restarting over and over,

Tags: boot, dual-boot, windows-7

I have a problem. I installed Ubuntu 14.04.1 alongside my Windows 7. I did it that way : [tutorial link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LDjjJkpCcxg) . Everything during installation was good, but when it went to boot manager, nothing happened. My system started with Windows 7 as always but I didnt see any boot menu. To see the GRUB I used EasyBCD and I added entry with GRUB2. It .I started Ubuntu and smiled.But  GRUB worked once... After restart my PC I wanted to go on Windows 7 then blue screen appeared and my PC restarted. After that fact my computer restarting over and over, and the only thing I can see is a dell logo. I checked disc by Ubuntu Trial and I didnt loose any data. Boot-pair didnt help me. I tried also set BIOS to default. 
What can i do?

Here is a film: [Film with a problem](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XWwJG-edQDU)

Please help me, computer is my main tool during studies :(

Comment: windows 7, are there any errors for the blue screen? the instructions at this link have helped me in the past but they must be run from windows command line in a recovery environment or possibly from a repair disk, JUST DONT RUN THE MBR COMMAND, whatever you do. http://command-line-computer-virus.tumblr.com/tagged/windows_7

Comment: I can't start system recorvery options, F8, ctrl+F11 doesnt work , only F2 for BIOS setup and F12 for options :(

Comment: You will need to download a repair or install disk. I guess licensing doesn't really matter if you have a product code and you are not even going to install right? but I'm not a lawyer so I really have no clue about that stuff. If you have an MS windows install or repair disk, you can run the commands from cmd, there is usually an option to "repair" and you can select to manually repair yourself.

Comment: :( I have a recorvery partition, but I cant get there, I dont know what to do else :(

Comment: no, a repair disk or a windows install disk, you can run the bootrec commands from there and not do the install just use it to fix

Comment: So I have to burn a windows 7 on a DVD?

Comment: yeah, that will work

Comment: when you say blue screen, you are talking about a microsoft blue screen right?

Comment: I saw it once, now I see only dell logo and pc restarting I will share a film

Comment: Here is a film [link] https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XWwJG-edQDU [/link]

Comment: Please don't provide information in form of a film. It's too inefficient to retrieve information necessary to help you.

Comment: @mchid That idea with running bootrec commands didnt work :/

Answer (score 0):

This usually means that you didn't fully download Ubuntu next to Windows, or didn't download it at all. I did this once two. So before you turn your computer on put in your usb or cd with Ubuntu on it then turn it on, once you turn it on click f12 over and over until you get boot options, when you get that do what you have to do for downloading Ubuntu again. This time make sure it is fully downloaded, this should fix your problem.

Comment: But I downloaded full .iso file with ubuntu 14.04.1 . And used UUI to install it by USB.